# Ruby serializing and deserializing SSL parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, serialization

I am trying to serialize a ruby object( which contains some SSL parameters).

I tried

```
 Marshal::dump(that_object)
```

it's giving the error

```
no _dump_data is defined for class OpenSSL::X509::Certificate
```

I tried storing using

```
a = YAML::dump(that_object)
```

The object gets stored without any errors but when I tried

```
YAML::load(a)
```

The object gets loaded completely. but the values of `openSSL::X509 and OpenSSL::PKey::RSA` gets changed and some other attributes becaming nil.

My question is hoe to serialize objects with SSL parameters so that I can get the same object later.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not possible because the SSL data you refer to are not ruby objects but just pointers into the OpenSSL library. Which means you cannot simply serialize them. But thinks like X509 and RSA keys have their serializations independent from ruby, so look out for functions which convert these data to PEM or DER.